# Adding a background image to a UILabel

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios, uikit

I'm attempting to add a UIImageView to the subview of a UILabel, but for some reason, I'm unable to have it as the background as this will cover the actual label text.

I don't want to set the UILabel's background color as because it will repeat as a pattern:

```
[self setBackgroundColor: [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"someBg.png"]]];
```

Looking at the number of subviews to a raw UILabel it seems like the text isn't a UIView so adding the subview to index 0 won't help either.

I need the text to be ON TOP of the image background.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyhow I solved this by inheriting UITextField and adding the subview to that. This works since there's actually a UILabel subview within this control and adding it behind it naturally solves the problem.

Also, I disabled user interaction so that it behaves like a label.

Answer (score 5):

Your options:

- Wrap the label and the background image view in another container view.
- Write your own label class that supports background images.